# MS Virtual Mashines under Hyper-V (how to import)?

Tags: import, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I downloaded Win7 and Win8 VMs for Hyper-V from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

The problem is that I cannot import any of them. Hyper-V says just "I cannot find VM files"

I used that kind of VM before and do not remember problems. Ran out of ideas how to add them to my Hyper-V manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ok, as always you going crazay for hours and when you post the question, you find the solution.
I simply made new machine, attaching provided Virtual drive. Actually, I tried it before asking a question, yet with other option and it didn't work.